# Most of the old FCM Tokens Not Registered for Web

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, push

Script to Register Token FCM has been working correctly for the past year.
Suddenly, last night on sending push to token, it's returning not registered. If I invoke the GetToken from Firebase its still returning the same token which is not registered.

Most of my old Tokens are now not registered.

Is there a way to renew them via an API or resolve the not registered issue?

Comment: did you manage to solve this problem?

Comment: Instead solving this, I would be interested in knowing why it happened. Similar thing happened with me where 150,000 tokens got not registered in a day, whereas they worked the day before

Comment: @KedarParikh i have tried contacting FCM and they didn't provide any useful feedback , we had to wait till all these user repoened the website to renew their token.

Answer (score 0):

Just Clear Your Browsing History Will Do The Job